Spring rest repository jackson serializer problem
When I use Spring rest repository + spring security + spring session + redis,the type org.springframework.hateoas.Links cannot (de)serialization,the stacktrace as follows
2024-06-27T10:11:45.816+08:00 ERROR 23276 --- [java-spring-web-rest-repository] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.hateoas.Links]] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Type id handling not implemented for type org.springframework.hateoas.Links (by serializer of type org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource["_links"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1330) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer.serializeWithType(JsonSerializer.java:173) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:734) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:653) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:502) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:341) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1574) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1061) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:483) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:114) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.RepresentationModelProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(RepresentationModelProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.java:134) ~[spring-hateoas-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:151) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:129) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:175) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142) ~[spring-session-core-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]

I try:

add dependency jackson-databind to pom
add dependency spring-boot-starter-hateoas to pom
register Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer Bean to IOC container
Override StdSerializer
implements HypermediaMappingInformation
register MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter Bean to IOC container


Based on the error log, it seems that handling for the type ID of the Links type has not been implemented.
Type id handling not implemented for type org.springframework.hateoas.Links (by serializer of type org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource["_links"]) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]
This exception can be resolved by enabling the objectMapper to serialize HATEOAS.
It should work correctly if you add the module as follows.
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    return mapper;
}

ps. The question you posted does not include code, so my answer may not be entirely accurate. If you update your question to include the code, I can provide a more precise response.

Additionally, it would be helpful if you could include the code where the exception occurred when posting your questions in the future. Thank you.
